# How to use Ruby's "git" gem to push back to GitHub

Tags: ruby, git, github

When I try to use the `git` gem to push, I get this error: `src refspec master does not match any`.  My repo uses `main` instead of `master`; but (assuming that is the problem), I don't see how to change the upstream branch.

Details:

I am writing a Ruby script that modifies a set of existing, already cloned repositories and pushes the changes. I'm using the `git` gem (https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git)

Here is the minimal example:

```
git_dir = '.'
begin
  $stderr.puts "Opening with git_dir: #{git_dir}"
  g = Git.open("#{git_dir}", :raise => true)
  g.config('remote.remote-name.push', 'refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main')
  $stderr.puts "Current branch:  #{g.current_branch}"

  if g.status.changed.any?
    g.add
    g.commit('Updated grade report')
    g.push(branch: g.current_branch)
  else
    $stderr.puts "No changes"
  end
rescue Git::GitExecuteError => e
  puts "Problem updating repo"
  puts "error: #{e.message}"
end
```

I run this program after modifying a file in an existing, previously cloned git repo.
When I do, it fails with this error:

```
Problem updating repo
error: git '--git-dir=testGitRepo' '-c' 'core.quotePath=true' '-c' 'color.ui=false' push '{:branch=>"main"}' 'master'  2>&1:error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '{:branch=>"main"}'
```

I suspect the important part of this error message is  `push '{:branch=>"main"}' 'master'`

The fact that `master` still appears suggests that I need to do something else to tell the `push` command that I want to push the local `main` to `origin main`; but, I don't see how to do that.

---

The docs for `push` say this:

```
pushes changes to a remote repository - easiest if this is a cloned repository, otherwise you may have to run something like this first to setup the push parameters:

@git.config('remote.remote-name.push', 'refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master')
```

But I don't see how to call `config` in a way that sets the upstream branch to main.  (I tried  `g.config('remote.remote-name.push', 'refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main')` and it appeared to have no effect.  Of course, I don't fully understand what this command is supposed to do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` takes the remote and branch names as separate arguments:

```
#push(remote = 'origin', branch = 'master', opts = {})
```

https://rubydoc.info/gems/git/Git/Base#push-instance_method

Using the following should work:

```
g.push('origin', 'main')
```

Comment: Ugh. I was misreading the documentation. Somehow I got it in my head that  `remote` and `branch` were keyword parameters, not positional.